# Mixing data from two tables in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one called location_name it looks like this,

```
location  shortname longname  precolor     color     hidden

       1    STO     Stockholm   #00FF00     #FF0000     0
       2    GBG     Gothenburg  #00FFFF     #FF00FF     0
       3    MMO     MalmÃ¶      #C6C6C6     #008000     0
       4    CPH     Copenhagen  #FF0080     #FF8000     0
       5    ARH     Ã…rhus      #80FF80     #8000FF     1
       6    SER     Service     #FFFF00     #FFFF00     1
```

and the other one, called art_tot, looks lite this

```
artnr   art     art_text     gnr       gnr_group    sortorder   hide    location    
220101  Thing   description  2201      1            101         0       3
220102  Thing   description  2201      1            102         0       2 
220103  Thing   description  2201      1            103         0       3
```

and im making a  that looks something like this

```
 Pos    Equipment   Artnr  Mon 27-10-2014   Tue 28-10-2014  Wed 29-10-2014  Thu 30-10-2014  Fri 31-10-2014  Sat 01-11-2014  Sun 02-11-2014
 STO    Thing       220101
 STO    Thing       220102
 STO    Thing       220103
 STO    Thing       222001
```

What i need to do is, color the Pos to the correct color from location_name and have the correct shortname and have the title be the longname.

So i somehow have to make the the Pos TD get the correct values from location_name based on the location column from art_tot

Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: You've tagged this with PHP. In general it's best to handle issues of data display in the presentation layer/applicaiton-level code (e.g. PHP) so just gather an ordered array and do the rest with a simple PHP loop.

Comment: Look at the JOIN facilities http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: do as @dwhite.me mentions on understanding what a JOIN does and then come back and post what you tried if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i read about JOIN and ended up doing :

```
$sql ="SELECT a.art_text , a.art , a.art , a.artnr , b.color , b.longname, b.shortname
        FROM art_tot a , location_name b 
        where gnr_group =1 AND a.location = b.location
        order by sortorder" ;
```

It works like a charm, thanks @dwhite.me

Comment: @Strawberry It says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days" when i try

Comment: I was 'passing by' and your answer works for your question and you did it yourself. +1 from me. Talking it (the problem) out often helps to clarify the problem and gives 'clues' to the solution.